# .prop('checked',false) or .removeAttr('checked')?

Tags: jquery

With the introduction of the prop method, now I need to know the accepted way of unchecking a checkbox.  Is it:

```
$('input').filter(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

or

```
$('input').filter(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: Have you read John Resig's post? http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/

Answer (score 149, accepted):

**jQuery 3**

As of jQuery 3, `removeAttr` does *not* set the corresponding property to `false` anymore:

> Prior to jQuery 3.0, using `.removeAttr()` on a boolean attribute such as `checked`, `selected`, or `readonly` would also set the corresponding named property to `false`. This behavior was required for ancient versions of Internet Explorer but is not correct for modern browsers because the attribute represents the initial value and the property represents the current (dynamic) value.
>
> It is almost always a mistake to use `.removeAttr( "checked" )` on a DOM element. The only time it might be useful is if the DOM is later going to be serialized back to an HTML string. In all other cases, `.prop( "checked", false )` should be used instead.

[Changelog](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-removeattr-no-longer-sets-properties-to-false)

Hence only `.prop('checked',false)` is correct way when using this version.

---

**Original answer (from 2011):**

For attributes which have underlying boolean properties (of which `checked` is one), `removeAttr` automatically sets the underlying property to `false`. (Note that this is among the backwards-compatibility "fixes" added in jQuery 1.6.1).

So, either will work... but the second example you gave (using `prop`) is the more correct of the two. If your goal is to uncheck the checkbox, you really do want to affect the *property*, not the attribute, and there's no need to go through `removeAttr` to do that.

Comment: @tandu: You *can*, but you shouldn't. From the docs: "**Note:** Do not use [`removeProp()`] to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use `.prop()` to set these properties to false instead." `removeProp` is really intended for use with custom properties only.

Answer (score 25):

use `checked` : true, false property of the checkbox.

jQuery:

```
if($('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
} else {
    $(this).prop('checked',false);
}
```

Comment: We can eliminate if, else using one liner, $(this).prop('checked', $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked'));

Comment: how can we mention the ctrl id to be checked for status?

Comment: if($(''#id').is(':checked')) {
    $(this).prop('checked',true);
} else {
    $(this).prop('checked',false);
}

Answer (score 16):

I recommend to use both, prop and attr because I had problems with Chrome and I solved it using both functions.

```
if ($(':checkbox').is(':checked')){
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', true).attr('checked', 'checked');
}
else {
    $(':checkbox').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('checked');
}
```

Comment: Yes, for chrome, use :

`$("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']").prop("checked", false).attr("checked", false).removeAttr("checked");`

Comment: I use custom component (CSS + JS) to replace input radio and checkbox. This is the only one way which works for me. Thanks!

Comment: @ragnar this solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to do the same thing is to filter on *type=checkbox* attribute:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

or

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked' , false);
```

From the [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

> The difference between *attributes* and *properties* can be important in specific situations. **Before jQuery 1.6**, the [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. **As of jQuery 1.6**, the `.prop()` method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

Comment: The question was "Which one of these is more correct", ?not "Are there any other ways of doing this?". You don't appear to have attempted to answer the question

Answer (score -4):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   

  

  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" onchange='act(this)'>
     
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" onchange='act(this)'>
  
  <script>
  
  
   function act(element){
   
       if($(element). prop('checked'))  
       {
           console.log('You have Checked it');
       }else
       {
        console.log('You Un-Checked it');
       }
   }
   
   </script>
```

Comment: This code snippet does not answer the original question of what is the accepted (correct) way of unchecking a checkbox.