# Remove Checked attribute of a radio button in a table

Tags: jquery

Here is my code, i want to clrae the response of radio when i click on the button.

```
<table class='x'>
<tr><td><input type="radio"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id="a" value="dfrfvrgv">
```

Here is the jQuery code

```
$('#a').click(function()
          {
              $('TABLE .x').find('input').removeAttr('checked');  
          });
```

But it is not working, Seems to be problem with the code. Please someone help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For jquery < 3.0:

```
$('#a').click(function() {
            $('TABLE.x').find('input').removeAttr('checked');  
        });
```

For jquery >= 3.0:

```
$('#a').click(function() {
            $('TABLE.x').find('input').prop('checked', false);  
        });

// More info about removeAttr and prop you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked
```

No space in the selector

What you are looking for with the space in there, are any child nodes of TABLE that have the class x.  table.x looks for a table with the class of x.

Answer (score 2):

`$('table.x')` is the right selector

Answer (score 1):

There was a space in the selector. Try the code below:

```
$('#a').click(function()
          {
              $('TABLE.x').find('input').removeAttr('checked');  
          });
```