# Why can't I enable and uncheck an element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I want to enable and set check = false by editing this code?

```
if (confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
    $(​'table tr input[type=hidden]').filter(function() {
        return $(this).val()​​​​​ == widgetId;
    }).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').attr({disabled: true, checked: true});
```

I try :

```
.siblings('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('disabled');
```

and this.

```
.siblings('input[type=checkbox]').attr({disabled:false, checked: false});
```

but in vain

---

## EDIT 1:

```
<table><colgroup><col title="process name"></colgroup> <tbody><tr><td><input name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl0$hf_id" id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_hf_id" value="91" type="hidden"> <input id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_chb_sys" name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl0$chb_sys" type="checkbox"> <span id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_lbl_main_sys">pro1</span> </td></tr></tbody></table><table><colgroup><col title="processname"> </colgroup><tbody><tr><td><input name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl1$hf_id" id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl1_hf_id" value="92" type="hidden"><input id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl1_chb_sys" name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl1$chb_sys" type="checkbox"> <span id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl1_lbl_main_sys">pro2</span> </td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I wanna to enable input type="checkbox" if the value of the input type ="hidden" that exist in the same `<td>` equal to the id of `li`(widget).This when the user click close.

Comment: I'm wondering, are you trying to set checkboxes according to a preference, and then setting them to `disabled: true` so the user can't toggle that checkbox?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, but see my attempt at an answer.

Comment: hmmm , i don't know why down vote!!

Comment: `// Disable checkboxes which have a sibling hidden input field with value equal to widgetId`  

Your code does not do what you commented, it would be more:

`// Disable checkboxes which are siblings of hidden input fields with value equal to widgetId`

Can we see a bit of your HTML to understand what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(​'table tr input[type="hidden"][value="'+widgetId+'"]')
       .siblings(':checkbox').attr("disabled": false).attr("checked": false);
```

Comment: i need the opposite :

enabled and not checked

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `prop` instead of `attr`:
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

```
.siblings('input[type=checkbox]').prop({"disabled": false, "checked": false});
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do this with jQuery.

To enable

```
$('#element').removeAttr('disabled');
```

To uncheck

```
$('#element').removeAttr('checked');
```

Or, even Combine them

```
$('#element').removeAttr('disabled').removeAttr('checked');
```

---

Just in case, you manipulated the attribute after it has been loaded, then it will no longer be available as an attribute from **jQuery 1.6**.

If you are using so and later, try `.removeProp( propertyName )` <sup>*[[docs here]](http://api.jquery.com/removeProp/)*</sup> instead.

```
$('#element').removeProp('disabled').removeProp('checked');
```

## Update

- **Update 1:** It does work. Check a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xBquz/).
- **Update 2:** I have also simulated the manipulation and created another fiddle using .removeProp(), check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xBquz/3/)
- **Update 3:** Ok, check [this update](http://jsfiddle.net/xBquz/6/). It it compatible with your markup, however, you might have to use proper selector, for you. However, this will give you the entire idea.

Comment: `$('table tr input[type=hidden]').filter(function() {
                            return $(this).val() == widgetId;
                        }).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').removeProp('disabled').removeProp('checked');`

Comment: Using `.prop({disabled: false, checked: false})` [works as well](http://jsfiddle.net/xBquz/2/).

Comment: because i try this :
`if (confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
                        // Disable checkboxes which have a sibling hidden input field with value equal to widgetId
                        $('table tr input[type=hidden]').filter(function() {
                            return $(this).val() == widgetId;
                        }).siblings('input[type=checkbox]').removeProp('disabled').removeProp('checked');`
and it doesn't work.

Comment: @just_name, Ok, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xBquz/4/), it is somewhat similar to what you need. If you need, actual code, update your question with the markup as well.

Comment: @just_name, Can you just pick out the related markup and update your post on your question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if this is somewhere along what you're trying to do. I had to come up with some stand-in markup, and I have no idea where `widgetId` comes from. However, is this the effect you're after?

**EDIT** - I'm not really sure what `widgetId` is doing here, and my original code was ignoring it, so I modified the code to run off the `input:button` click, which will manipulate it's siblings.

**Sample HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test1"/></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="widget"/>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test2"/></label>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test3"/></label>
            <input type="button" class="check" value="Check"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test1"/></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="widget"/>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test2"/></label>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test3"/></label>
            <input type="button" class="check" value="Check"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test1"/></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="widget"/>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test2"/></label>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test3"/></label>
            <input type="button" class="check" value="Check"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.check').click(function(){
    var $td = $(this).parent('td');

    if (!confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
        $td.find(':checkbox').prop({disabled: true, checked: true});
    } else {
        $td.find(':checkbox').prop({disabled: false, checked: false});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SPVPx/1/

**EDIT 2**

A different example, using `input:button`s not within the `table`.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" class="check" value="Remove Widget 1" data-widget-id="widget1"/>
<input type="button" class="check" value="Remove Widget 2" data-widget-id="widget2"/>
<input type="button" class="check" value="Remove Widget 3" data-widget-id="widget3"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Widget 1:
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test1"/></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="widget1"/>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test2"/></label>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test3"/></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Widget 2:
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test1"/></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="widget2"/>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test2"/></label>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test3"/></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Widget 3:
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test1"/></label>
            <input type="hidden" value="widget3"/>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test2"/></label>
            <label>Checkbox <input type="checkbox" value="test3"/></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
// For testing only.
$(':checkbox').prop({disabled: true, checked: true});

$('.check').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('widget-id'),
        $td = $('table tr td input:hidden').filter(function(){
            return this.value == id;
        }).parent('td');

    if (confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {
        $td.find(':checkbox').prop({disabled: false, checked: false});
    } else {
        $td.find(':checkbox').prop({disabled: true, checked: true});
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SPVPx/2/

Comment: This is the real question but when i revise my recommendation i find my self need the opposite .i mean :

`Enabled and checked = false` instead of the answer

Comment: It make checked = false as i want but still disabled

Comment: it works perfectly on `firefox`.but The IE can't Enable the checkbox

Comment: yes , it works like this in the `firefox` . but in `IE` just make checked = false ,it 's still disabled .

Comment: from firebug : my check box like this :

`<td>
<input id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_hf_id" type="hidden" value="91" name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl0$hf_id">
<span disabled="disabled">
<input id="rlv_mainservices_ctrl0_chb_sys" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked" name="rlv_mainservices$ctrl0$chb_sys">
</span>
......
`

Comment: Is there any fix to this problem for IE?

Comment: Nevermind, it appears it was a jsFiddle-related problem. See: http://jfcoder.com/test/disable.html

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked) for why to use `.removeAttr()` instead of `.removeProp()`.

Comment: This is my last update but the same problem with IE only:
`$(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function() {
 var widgetId = this.id;
var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(widgetId);
$('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();}).click(function() {
$td = $('table tr td input:hidden').filter(function() {
return this.value == widgetId;}).parent('td');
                    if (confirm('This widget will be removed, ok?')) {                $td.find(':checkbox').removeAttr('disabled').removeAttr('checked');`

Comment: I think that you'll need to do some debugging on your own here, with IE9's `console.log()`, to check different values and whatnot, see if they're what you expect (of if you're getting errors at all).