# Remove attribute "checked" of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I need remove the attribute "checked" of one checkbox when errors occur.

The .removeAttr function not work. Any idea? :/

HTML

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <input type="checkbox" id="captureImage" name="add_image" class="custom" />
    <label for="captureImage" data-icon="checkbox">Image</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="captureAudio" name="add_audio" class="custom" />
    <label for="captureAudio" data-icon="checkbox">Audio</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="captureVideo" name="add_video" class="custom" />
    <label for="captureVideo" data-icon="checkbox">Video</label>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#captureImage").live("change", function() {
    // $("#captureImage").prop('checked', false); // Here Work

    if($("#captureImage:checked").val() !== undefined) {
            navigator.device.capture.captureImage(function(mediaFiles) {
            console.log("works");
        }, function(exception) {
            $("#captureImage").prop('checked', false); // Not Works Here
            _callback.error(exception);
        }, {limit: 1});
    }
});

/*
$("#captureAudio").live("change", function() {
    if($("#captureAudio:checked").val() !== undefined) {
            navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(function(mediaFiles) {
            console.log("audio");
        }, function() {
            $("#captureAudio").removeAttr('checked');
            _callback.error;
        }, {limit: 1});
    }
});

$("#captureVideo").live("change", function() {
    if($("#captureVideo:checked").val() !== undefined) {
            navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(function(mediaFiles) {
            console.log("video");
        }, function(exception) {
            $("#captureVideo").prop('checked', false);
            _callback.error(exception);
        }, {limit: 1});
    }
});
*/
```

Comment: $("#captureImage:checked").val() will always give you val on or off even you have not defined value for it

Comment: @rajeshkakawat No, $("#captureImage").val() is different of $("#captureImage:checked").val()

Comment: Yes, is different, but the conditional its works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.prop('checked',false) or .removeAttr('checked')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this to check

```
$('#captureImage').attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

and uncheck

```
$('#captureImage').attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 113):

Try...

```
$("#captureAudio").prop('checked', false);
```

Comment: It doesn't work in a callback error function, it works only out of the captureImage function.

Answer (score 75):

Both of these should work:

```
$("#captureImage").prop('checked', false);
```

AND/OR

```
$("#captureImage").removeAttr('checked');
```

... you can try both together.

Comment: Only the second option worked for me but I dont know why. Is it because I set the checked attribute with the attr method, like: radio.attr('checked', 'checked')?

Comment: @ErikČerpnjak yes then

Comment: **NOTE** per [.prop('checked',false) or .removeAttr('checked')?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6169826/1366033), that **`.prop( "checked", false )`** is always preferable to `.removeAttr( "checked" )`

Answer (score 5):

I use prop attribute for `unchecked` the `checkbox` when errors occur.
You don't need to use remove property for unchecked your checkbox.

```
$('input#IDName').prop('checked', false);
```

It is working fine for me. Hope it will work for you also.

Answer (score 4):

using `.removeAttr()` on a boolean attribute such as `checked`, `selected`, or `readonly` would also set the corresponding named property to `false`.

Hence removed this checked attribute

```
$("#IdName option:checked").removeAttr("checked");
```

Answer (score 4):

In case someone's looking for an answer using pure JavaScript:

```js
const audioLabel = document.getElementById('captureAudio');

audioLabel.removeAttribute('checked');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#captureAudio")[0].checked = false;
```

Comment: I guess you are doing wrong the condition. Try: `if ( $("#captureImage")[0].checked )`. Avoid using those jQuery pseudo-selectors (`:checked`).

Comment: @FabianoLothor also avoid raising Exceptions. Even something like `console.error` may crash your code. (It has happened to me)

Comment: the condition is working properly. The problem is I can not run JQuery calls within the error function.

Comment: @FabianoLothor then, cache the variable. `captureImage = $("#captureImage")` (do it after the call to navigator). Then, in the callback function, just do: `captureImage[0].checked = false`

Answer (score 2):

You could try `$(this)`:

```
$("#captureAudio").live("change", function() {
    if($(this).val() !== undefined) { /* IF THIS VALUE IS NOT UNDEFINED */
            navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(function(mediaFiles) {
            console.log("audio");
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('checked'); /* REMOVE checked ATTRIBUTE; */
            /* YOU CAN USE `$(this).prop("checked", false);` ALSO */
            _callback.error;
        }, {limit: 1});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HMb2p/)

```
    try
      {
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(function(mediaFiles) {
        console.log("works");
         });
      }

    catch(err)
      {
        alert('hi');
        $("#captureImage").prop('checked', false);

      }
```

Comment: I try here, but, not entry on catch. :/

Answer (score -7):

Sorry, I solved my problem with the code above:

```
$("#captureImage").live("change", function() {
    if($("#captureImage:checked").val() !== undefined) {
        navigator.device.capture.captureImage(function(mediaFiles) {
            console.log("works");
        }, function(exception) {
            $("#captureImage").removeAttr('checked').checkboxradio('refresh');
            _callback.error(exception);
        }, {});
    }
});
```