# Why when checked checkbox it's will show incorrect data value?

Tags: javascript

Why when checked checkbox it's will show incorrect data value ?a ?

First, Load page `index.php` it's will display `All` it's OK.

But when you checked checkbox `Red` it's will display `All` and `Red`

Why not show only `Red` ?

index.php

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("#f_id").submit(send_data_requests());
</script>

<form method="post" id="f_id" action="Javascript:void(0);" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="all_color" name="all_color" value="All" onclick="send_data_requests()" checked >All<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color_red" name="color_red" value="Red" onclick="send_data_requests()">Red<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="color_blue" name="color_blue" value="Blue" onclick="send_data_requests()">Blue<br>
</form>

<div id="data_areas">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$('#all_color').click(function () {   
     $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
     $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);           
 });

$("#color_red").click(function() {
    $("#all_color").prop('checked', false);
});

$("#color_blue").click(function() {
    $("#all_color").prop('checked', false);
});

});

</script>

<script>
function send_data_requests()
    {
        $('#data_areas').hide();
        $.ajax
            (
                {
                    url: 'datas.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $('#f_id').serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data)
                        {
                            $('#data_areas').show();
                            $('#data_areas').html(data);
                        }
                }
            );
        return false;
    }
// on load page call function code //
$(document).ready(send_data_requests());
</script>
```

datas.php

```
<?php
echo $_POST[all_color];
echo "<BR>";
echo $_POST[color_red];
echo "<BR>";
echo $_POST[color_blue];
?>
```

Comment: `$(this).prop("checked", "checked");`  <--- makes no sense

Comment: The property 'checked' is a `boolean`: `true` or `false`.

Comment: Why has this same code been posted under 2 accounts? [Same ids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848320/when-sub-checkbox-was-discheck-i-want-to-auto-checked-main-checkbox-how-can-i)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('#all_color').removeAttr('checked');`

instead of `$("#all_color").prop('checked', false);`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fhz7bqu/10/).

For some reason (which i would like to know as well*) the prop method does not remove the "checked" attribute from the checkbox, even though it un-checks it.

**Edit:**
*seems like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked) gives an explanation