# How to update siblings checkbox with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I am attempting to implement JavaScript to update the checkbox siblings in it's corresponding div. I have multiple div's that have the same checkbox options: #check_all_checkboxes,  #check_none, and .others. I want the div to update their siblings, but the JavaScript will not update the siblings. I can hardcode the sibling class or id and the JavaScript will successfully execute on the first div, but not on the successive div's.

```
    // Select ALL checkboxes
    $('#check_all_checkboxes').click(function () {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $(this).siblings('.others').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).siblings('#check_none').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });

    // Select NO checkbox(es)
    $('#check_none').click(function () {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
            $(this).siblings('.others').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).siblings('#check_all_checkboxes').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });

    // Select other checkbox(es)
    $('.others').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('#check_none').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).siblings('#check_all_checkboxes').removeAttr('checked');
    });
```

Comment: Please show associated html. We can't determine proper traverses without seeing it. Am guessing that you are repeating ID's in page but they must be unique by definition

Answer (score 1):

This post suggests you may be better served with .prop('checked', false) :
[.prop('checked',false) or .removeAttr('checked')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked)

Answer (score 0):

With the advice of charlietfl on the use of unique ID's and not repeating ID's. I was able to get this working with using class.

```js
// Select ALL checkboxes
$('.check_all_checkboxes').click(function () {
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $(this).siblings('.others').prop('checked', true);
    $(this).siblings('.check_none').removeAttr('checked');
  }
});

// Select NO checkbox(es)
$('.check_none').click(function () {
  if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $(this).siblings('.others').removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).siblings('.check_all_checkboxes').removeAttr('checked');
  }
});

// Select other checkbox(es)
$('.others').click(function () {
  $(this).siblings('.check_none').removeAttr('checked');
  $(this).siblings('.check_all_checkboxes').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

```html
<div id="1">
    Div ID 1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_all_checkboxes">Select All<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_none">Select None<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="others">Select other1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="others">Select other2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="others">Select other3<br>   
</div>        

<hr>        
        
<div id="2">
    Div ID 2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_all_checkboxes">Select All<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check_none">Select None<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="others">Select other1<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="others">Select other2<br>
    <input type="checkbox" class="others">Select other3<br>   
</div>
```