# Changing input box also need to find check box checked or not in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input box along with checkbox in table `<td>` like below,

```
<td>
    <input class="Comment" type="text" data-db="comment" data-id="{{uid}}"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="summary" title="Check to set as Summary" />
</td>
```

Based on check box only the content of input box will be stored in DB.

In the JS file, I tried like

```
var updateComment = function( eventData )
{
    var target = eventData.target;
    var dbColumn = $(target).attr('data-db');
    var api = $('#api').val();
    var newValue = $(target).val();
    var rowID = $(target).attr('data-id');
    var summary = $('#summary').is(':checked');
    params = { "function":"updatecomments", "id": rowID, "summary": summary };
    params[dbColumn] = newValue;
    jQuery.post( api, params);
};

$('.Comment').change(updateComment);
```

But the `var summary` always returning `false`.

I tried so many ways `prop('checked')`,`(#summary:checked).val()` all are returning false only.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: you have not put `$` in `('#summary').is(':checked');` . Do `$('#summary').is(':checked');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have multiple rows of `checkboxes + input` fields in your table. So doing `$('#summary').is(':checked')` will return the value of first matching element since `id` in a DOM should be unique.

So, modify your code like this:

```
<td>
    <input class="Comment" type="text" data-db="comment" data-id="{{uid}}"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="summary" title="Check to set as Summary" />
</td>
```

And, instead of `$('#summary').is(':checked');` you can write like this:

```
var summary = $(target).parent().find(".summary").is(':checked');
```

By doing this, we are making sure that we are checking the value of checkbox with the selected input field only.

**Update:** For listening on both the conditions i.e. when **when checking checkbox first and then typing input box** and **when first typing input box and then checked**:

Register the change event for checkbox:

```
// Whenever user changes any checkbox
$(".summary").change(function() {
    // Trigger the "change" event in sibling input element
    $(this).parent().find(".Comment").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Agarwal..wow!!..good catch..it is working perfectly..but working when checking checkbox first and  then typing input box,not working first typing input box and then checked..is there any other way to check both the conditions?

Comment: Thank you so much..its working fine.. I edited like `$(".summary").change(function() {
 
    $(this).parent().find(".Comment").trigger("change");
});
var summary = $(target).parent().find(".summary").is(':checked');`    is this correct form?

Comment: Glad this works! I didn't get your question. What is the use of `var summary = $(target).parent().find(".summary").is(':checked');` after the `.change()` function?

Comment: Thats my question..use of `var summary`.but I need to pass 'summary' value(true or false) to api..thats why I used  after `.change()` function..is this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the jQuery function --> $

```
 $('#summary').is(':checked')
```

`('#summary')` is a string wrapped in Parentheses. `$` is an alias for the jQuery function, so  `$('#summary')` is calling jquery with the selector as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
var summary = $('#summary').prop('checked');
```

*The `prop()` method gets the property value*

For more details, please visit below link.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6170016/2240375

Comment: Still it returning false only.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that `attr()` always works.

```
var chk_summary = false;

var summary = $("#summary").attr('checked');
if ( summary === 'checked') {
    chk_summary = true;  
}
```

and then use value `chk_summary`

Comment: Now also false only..I think the problem is with jquery version..I am using jquery v1.11.2..am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change all the occurrences of

```
 eventData
```

To

```
event
```

because event object has a property named `target`.

And you should have to know `change` event fires when you leave your target element. So, if checkbox is checked first then put some text in the input text and apply a blur on it, the it will produce `true`.