# jquery checkbox reset - inconsistent operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to use Jquery to reset checkboxes.  I've read the Q/A on the topic and came up with this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clearall").click(function(){
        alert('clearing checkboxes');
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    });
});
</script>
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" checked >
<button id="clearall">Click me</button>
```

On load, two checkboxes appear checked.  Clicking the button clears them.  This is as expected.  What is NOT expected is that if I check the boxes and click the button, the check boxes do NOT clear.  No javascript errors or warnings appear. I've checked the functionality in Firefox, Safari and Chrome - and all 3 operate the same way.  I inserted an alert which fires on every attempt, so the function is executing - but the checkboxes aren't getting reset after the first time. Can anyone offer any insight into why the check boxes do NOT clear if set by the user?

Comment: It works for me. Anyway, try this method [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) as well.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown For purpose of future proofing, do not use `.removeAttr()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked

Comment: @Terry good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Tip: when dealing with boolean attributes (such as disabled, checked, selected, etc.), use `.prop()` and **never use `.attr()`, `.removeProp()`, or `.removeAttr()`.** Why? This is because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked) and [this](http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/).

- `.attr()` and `.removeAttr()`: properties are dynamic and attributes are not--they reflect the initial value.
- `.removeProp()`:

  > Note: Do not use `removeProp()` to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clearall").click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cb1" type="checkbox" checked>
<input id="cb2" type="checkbox" checked >
<button id="clearall">Click me</button>
```

Comment: @user7491506 Do you really want me to google that for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked and http://ejohn.org/blog/jquery-16-and-attr/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.removeAttr('checked')`