# jQuery checkbox disable and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a table which have list of rows and every row have two checkboxes 
what I am trying to do is when someone check on check box it send request to server using ajax and reponsev with data if it pass it change the tr color to green if fail it change to red..I am done with this step

Now I want when it is success it should enable other check box which is on the same tr so now user can process with the second step.

```js
$("#SendReview").click(function() {

  var selected = "";
  $('.ReviewForm').each(function() {
    selected = selected + "," + $(this).attr('id');
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("VerifyFormRquest", "Results")',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      scanid: selected
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      alert(data.success);

      data.success.split(',').forEach(function(c) {
        if (c != "") {
          var m = $('#example tr:has(td:contains(' + c + '))').css('background-color', 'lightgreen');
        }
      });
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {}
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr id="1000000107">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="J15000001" scanid="1000000103" onclick="call()" disabled="disabled" value="1000000103" class="ELOchecked">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="1000000107">
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" id="J15000012" scanid="1000000107" disabled="disabled" value="1000000107" class="ELR">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: He said what he is trying to do. He wants to enable the second checkbox on success of his AJAX request.

Comment: you need to implement the call() function, that has an ajax call. inside the ajax call, if success enable the other checkbox and whatever you need, if fails add you code into the error function of the ajax

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the `prop` method.

`$("#myOtherCheckbox").prop("disabled", false);`

If you want to add a class to it as well:

`$("#myOtherCheckbox").prop("disabled", false).addClass("someClass");`

Comment: Not mine .. but `$("#myOtherCheckbox")` isn't really the correct selector to do this... _I have a table which have list of rows and every row have two checkboxes_ which line your selector will target ?

Comment: what i did now i add labid as class in my class and then     $('.' + c).prop('disabled', false);  thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
("#J15000012").prop("disabled",false);
```

to check the checkbox rather than using the `.removeAttr` as it does not set the value to `false` as of `jquery 3`

Comment: He is trying to enable the checkbox, not check it.

Comment: yes you are right I overlooked `enabled` as `checked`  @Adosi

Comment: what i did now i add labid as class in my class and then     $('.' + c).prop('disabled', false);  thanks!!

Comment: that is the right way to do as `.removeattr` does not set property to false anymore `.prop` is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the pattern to get the `td` you could get the next one using `next('td')`:

```
var current_td = $('#example td:contains('+ c +')');

//If the current td found get the next one and remove the disabled property
if( current_td.length > 0 ){
    current_td.next('td').prop('checked',false);
}
```

Comment: Using `.prop` is more preferred in this case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169826/propchecked-false-or-removeattrchecked

Comment: what i did now i add labid as class in my class and then     $('.' + c).prop('disabled', false);  thanks!!

Comment: As of jQuery 3, `removeAttr` does not set the corresponding property to `false` anymore using `.prop` is the correct way to set property to true or false

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam .. already mentioned in the first comment.